# "Index and length must refer to a location within the string" when I'm trying to create a substring

Tags: c#, string, indexing, substring

I'm getting this error and I cant seem to get why.

```
    private void MessageReceived(String message)
    {
        int beginIndex = message.IndexOf(":");
        String index = message.Substring(1, beginIndex - 1);
        if (index == "SHOW_TIME")
        {
            String time = message.Substring(11, message.Length -1);
            if (alarm == time)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM");
            }
        }
    }
```

The error pops in when the program gets to the String time line.

Comment: Suppose your string(message) doesn't contain `:` or its length is less than 11

Comment: the message string contains: #SHOW_TIME:xxxx%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting at index 11, but attempting to go until `message.Length - 1`. That will put you outside the end of the array which is causing the error.  You need to go until `message.Length - 12`;

```
String time = message.Substring(11, message.Length - 12);
```